# How does Entity Framework 6 implement Inner joins?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have defined the following two classes:

```
 public class tblInstrument
 {

     [Key]
     public int InstrumentID { get; set; }
     public int MarketID { get; set; }
     public virtual tblMarket tblMarket { get; set; }

 }
```

and

```
[Table("tblMarket")]
public class tblMarket
{
    public tblMarket()
    {
        tblInstruments = new HashSet<tblInstruments>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int MarketID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblInstruments> tblInstruments { get; set; }

}
```

I'd like to know why the following code, when appended to the tblInstrument class, does not work:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullInstrumentName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}", tblMarket.Market.Trim(); }
    }
```

when I put a breakpoint on  it, I see that tblmarket is null but it is virtual which means it is "lazy loaded" so that may be why it is null but the FullInstrumentName property does not return the expected Market property of tblmarket (a string).    Can someone help me understand how Entity does joins?

Thanks
-Ed

Answer (score 1):

As by default this relationship will be Lazy Loaded, you need to override that behavior for the specifics scenarios when you need to use FullInstrumentName property:

```
DbContext.tblInstruments
    .Include( i => i.tblMarket )
    .Where( i.MarketID == xyz );
```

To use *Include* you need to import *System.Data.Entity* namespace.

As an alternative, if you find that you are going to use that property more than often, then you might consider to complete remove lazy load for that relationship, but this is something you need to carefully consider pro and cons.

Comment: Thanks.   Since tblMarket contains minimal data (just a few integer fields), I removed the Virtual so it would not lazy load.    Breakpoints still show a valid MarketID in a tblInstrument instance but a null tblMarket property?? I even tried converting the Getting into a method so I could single step and just creating a string with tblMarket.Market.Trim() causes the the debugger to "run"... I cannot single-step over the string assignment.

Comment: Did you removed the virtual keyword from public virtual tblMarket tblMarket { get; set; }? 
That effectively should disable lazy load for this navigation.

Comment: In the tblInstrument Class, I defined tblMarket without Virtual:         public  tblMarket tblMarket { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

EF wants that  you show him how to do the relation with the tables, so you need to map the foreign key of `tblMarket`, see the map:

```
 public class tblInstrument
 {

     [Key]
     public int InstrumentID { get; set; }
     public int MarketID { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("MarketID")]
     public virtual tblMarket tblMarket { get; set; }

 }
```

> So EF will map the `MarketID` with the primary key of the `tblMarket`

Comment: Thanks. I added the ForeignKey attribute but my problem did no go away.  Actually, it did not even complain that i needed a migration so I have to assume that EF understood that this was the FK? Anyway... still does not give me the expected result...

Comment: Sure, you will need to add a migration, without foreing key EF doesn't will map it. I really suggest you to add this migration because it will provide consistence in the relationship.

Comment: I did an "Add-Migration" and the Up() and Down() were empty.  Which means Entity found no difference in my code.  adding the attribute did not change Entity's assumptions. I will leave it there for clarity's sake but this was not the issue...

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was not using the .include() method to include the referenced table. So as in the example above, when I ask Entity to retrieve the Instrument table, I need to .include(a=> a.tblmarket)  as well.

-Ed

Comment: Ok, this is the same solution I proposed to you before. It makes more sense if you accept an answer when it solve your problem.

Comment: sorry. I see it now.   Accepted your answer.

Comment: No problem, please review this thread that explain how to properly accept an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429992/how-to-accept-an-answer-to-my-post